# When to use *(new Foo)

Tags: c++, dynamic, heap-memory, new-operator

So I read about the problem with having something like

```
Foo bar = *(new Foo());
```

because after `bar` is out of scope and gets deleted from the stack there is no way to clean up `Foo()` from the heap. Is there any practical use to it?

Comment: There are many things that one could write that don't have any "practical use". You seem to have identified the problem with this one. What prompted you to ask about this expression in particular? Did you see it used somewhere and are wondering why?

Comment: The object created by `new Foo()` leaks **immediately**. There is never a time to use this.

Comment: It's technically possible the default constructor of `Foo` stores the pointer to the created object somewhere and avoids the leak, but that would be extremely peculiar and brittle.

Comment: @StoryTeller, this doesn't have to be a leak, since the address of the dereferenced pointer may be saved by `bar`. Nonetheless, your comment pushes the OP in the right direction: stay away from such abominations!

Comment: @DanielTrugman - Very true. But I'd hate to work on a codebase with so non-obvious ownership semantics. So in my on micro-cosmos, this option doesn't apply :P

Comment: @StoryTeller, I hear ya :)

Comment: Start off with the premise of writing code that is readable and maintainable

Comment: @GregHewgill yes I saw it in a research paper but in a different context. Then I looked it up and didn't find any practical use. So I was wondering why this semantic is even allowed, this can't be intentionally done by a programmer can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Foo& foo = *(new Foo);
delete &foo;
```

But don't do that. It will confuse future maintainers, and there's no good reason for it. Use a pointer.

Comment: why exactly does this work? Why does printing out `foo` from my example and the one from yours return the same value?

Comment: @push_ebp -- your example creates a **copy** of the new object. My code creates a **reference** to the new object, without copying it. I don't know what "printing out `foo`" from your example does, because you didn't show the code for `Foo`.

Comment: I tried it with a simple `int& a = *(new int(10))` to test your answer. But shouldn't `cout << a` result in a printed out adress? Why is it printing `10` at that moment?

Comment: `std::cout << a << '\n';` prints the **object** that the **reference** `a` refers to. Just like `int i = 3; int& r = i; std::cout << r << '\n';`.